# In Swift 2, what changed in NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, ios9

In Swift 2, what exactly changed in the `NSDictionary(objects, forKeys)` *(Objective-C: dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:)* creation?

[Apple's prerelease documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:) was particularly useless, given that there only is Obj-C code. Even though there's a slight but obvious change in the provided snippet, I don't speak obj-c and haven't made sense out of the change so far.

Here's some code for you guys:

```
videoDataOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(objects: NSNumber(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), forKeys: (kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey))
//Working old Swift code; missing argument for parameter 'count' in call on Swift 2

+ (instancetype)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects
                              forKeys:(NSArray *)keys
//Old Obj-C code


+ (instancetype nonnull)dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray<ObjectType> * nonnull)objects
                                      forKeys:(NSArray<id<NSCopying>> * nonnull)keys
//New Obj-C code
```

I've read elsewhere that nonnull is supposed to facilitate compatibility with Swift, but what about `<ObjectType>`? And what's `id`?

@Update
Fixed swift code from `NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: )` to `NSDictionary(objects: , forKeys:)`

Comment: How did you fix it? NSDictionary(object: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as NSNumber, forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) is giving me 'OSType' is not convertible to 'NSNumber'

Comment: @PauloCesar I just ended up using the `Dictionary` literal, as explained in the end chosen answer

Comment: That also gives me error on Xcode beta 5. In the end it was simple to fix it: [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `+dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`, you are using `+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`. These are two different methods. `+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` is not supported by swift.

Using `+dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` would look like this.

```
videoDataOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(objects: [NSNumber(integer: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)], forKeys: [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey])
```

NOTE: I also needed to change `NSNumber(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)` to `NSNumber(integer: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)`

---

Because you only have one entry in the dictionary, you can use `+dictionaryWithObject:forKey:`.

```
videoDataOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(object: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as NSNumber, forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString)
```

NOTE 1: I used `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as NSNumber` instead of `NSNumber(integer: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)`

NOTE 2: I had to use `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString` instead of just `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`.

---

I think the simplest way to do this is to use swift's `Dictionary` literal.

```
videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
```

Comment: So `NSDictionary(object: NSNumber(integer: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), forKey: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)` should work, right?

Comment: No, `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` is of type `CFString!`. It needs to be converted into an `NSString`. I used `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString`, but you can use `NSString(string: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)` if you like that syntax better.

Comment: @osuka_ I think Jeffery's answer is more on-point than my answer. especially in regards to the preferred swift syntax.

Comment: I see. @JefferyThomas, one last question: on `videoDataOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(objects: [NSNumber(integer: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)], forKeys: [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey])`, why is `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` bracketed? Is it because it's of type CFString!?

Comment: `[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]` is an array with 1 item (the string `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`). `NSDictionary(objects:forKeys:)` takes arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work in XCode 7 Swift 2 using simply

```
output.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) ]
```

Check out this project for some current code https://github.com/gibachan/OpenCVSample/

Answer (score 1):

There is no real change for the obj-c programmer. It is mostly for the compiler and as you said for cross-compatibility to swift:

Instead of `(NSArray *)` you now have `(NSArray<ObjectType> * nonnull)` which means a) the array may not nonnull (not nil) and b) its contents / values must be of type `ObjectType`.

Instead of `(NSArray *)` you have `(NSArray<id<NSCopying>> * nonnull)` which means a) as above and b) its contents must adapt the `NSCopying` protocol.

Regarding the `expected count`: the `objectsAndKeys` is no longer present ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:)), you have to use some other function. or just a literal...

Final note regarding `id` and `ObjectType`: `id` refers to any object, you can sage every view or arra or anything as `id` - it has itself no type information. `ObjectType` I think refers to generics, it means that you write `ObjectType` everywhere you want to use a specific type, you dont know the type yet, but it will be the same at every place where `ObjectType` is written.

Comment: I pasted the wrong Swift code, my bad. Will edit in a couple minutes.  I used `objects: , forKeys: ` instead; code still broken. I still can't figure out how the obj-c changes translate to swift (or is it the other way around? If so, how should I update my Swift code?)

Comment: @osuka_ Yes, it will remain broken unless you fix it, you have to provide the count parameter. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithObjects:forKeys:count:

Comment: Okay, that's a start. What should I add, then? I didn't use any for Xcode 6

Comment: @osuka_ probably 1, judging from your code you only try to privde one key/value pair

Comment: @osuka_ Note that the docs as well as the xcode auto completion are having issues with the different initailizers :/

Comment: That explains a lot. Xcode has given me a few really bad suggestions. I'll try to add the count when I get home and I'll see how that goes